# Python Sub-process (Output PIPE)

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I read from output PIPE multiple times without using process.communicate() as communicate closes the PIPE after reading the output but I need to have sequential inputs and outputs.

For example,

1) `process.stdin.write('input_1')`

2) After that, I need to read the output `PIPE` (how can I accomplish that without using communicate as it closes the `PIPE`) and then give another input as

3) `process.stdin.write('input_2')`

4) And then read the output of step 3

But if I use `process.communicate` after giving first input then it closes the output `PIPE` and i am unable to give second input as the `PIPE` is closed.

Kindly help please.

Answer (score 1):

`flush()` stdin, then `read()` stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `process.communicate()`, use `process.stdout.read()`